New to FFmpeg and unsure on how to order arguments
I am new to using FFmpeg and would like to learn how to batch encode a folder of MKV files with the following parameters or what to do in these situations:

H264
MP4 output
Selection of certain audio track when multiple are present.
Selection of certain subtitle track when multiple have been embedded into the MKV file.
Burning in subtitle track to the video.
Adding black borders to both length and width of the video.

I am also unsure if the way the arguments are ordered matters. If someone could provide me with an example command or even explain a bit about each argument and/or if and why the order of arguments matters, I would greatly appreciate it.
Here is my attempt at writing a command:
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -map 0:a:1 -vf:s:1 subtitles=input.mkv -filter_complex [0]pad=w=112+iw:h=80+ih:x=56:y=40:color=black -crf 22 -output.mp4

I am not sure if I am missing anything in the example besides not knowing how to write an argument to batch encode an entire folder of video files.
I am very green with using the command line in general, not just with regards to FFmpeg.

Is your intention to use the second audio and hardcode the second subtitle for all videos in the folder?

To Ricardo Bohner: Not necessarily. I forgot 0 is for the first channels in my example.

With select do you mean turn it the default audio \ subtitle track or remove anything else?

emptylot4990: save as mp4 or mkv?

Ricardo Bohner: Preferably I need to have only one audio track and burned subtitles because the machine I am viewing the files on cannot switch between audio streams or subtitles. The source files are mkv and I want to encode them to mp4 as the machine cannot play mkv.

In a batch script it would be something like this to:
Use first audio stream + Hardcode first subtitle stream to the video and save in a mp4 container. In the Folder= part you have to set the folder where the videos are you want to convert. It saves a new video with same name as old but with _new.mp4 in the end.
@echo off

:: Specify here where your videos are:
Set "Folder=%userprofile%\Desktop"

cd /d "%Folder%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "*.mkv"') do (
ffmpeg -i "%%~a" -map 0:s:0 -c:s copy -y "%%~na_.srt" || del "%%~na_.srt"
ffmpeg -i "%%~a" -map 0:s:0 -c:s copy -y "%%~na_.ass" || del "%%~na_.srt"
                                                                            
if exist "%%~na_.srt" ffmpeg -i "%%~a" -map_chapters -1 -map_metadata -1 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -vf "subtitles='%%~na_.srt',pad=iw+112:ih+80:-1:-1:color=black" -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "%%~na_new.mp4"
if exist "%%~na_.ass" ffmpeg -i "%%~a" -map_chapters -1 -map_metadata -1 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -vf "subtitles='%%~na_.ass',pad=iw+112:ih+80:-1:-1:color=black" -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "%%~na_new.mp4"
if not exist "%%~na_.srt" if not exist "%%~na_.ass" "ffmpeg -i "%%~a" -map_chapters -1 -map_metadata -1 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -vf "pad=iw+112:ih+80:-1:-1:color=red" -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "%%~na_new.mp4"
)

pause 


It mostly appears to work, but I have another problem where the subtitles are gigantic and span the entire length and width of the video stream, mostly spilling off it altogether. I apologize for taking so long to respond, I was trying to compile ffmpeg with extra features to try your script again and it took a few hours. I appreciate your help.

Do the files where the subtitles get gigantic have an uncommon resolution? Maybe inverting the order in the video filter part apllying the subtitle first and next the padding...

This is how it should look like, except that I changed the black color for red so it gets more clear to see: https://sendvid.com/qc1qzfjx

Ricardo Bohner: Here is a still that hopefully illustrates the issue: https//:files.catbox.moe/t2gh1m.png

Are the original subtitles text based?

Ricardo Bohner: The original subtitles are already embedded into the mkv files. I am not sure how to describe them otherwise. The subtitles aren't inaccurate given your script, it's just that they are rendered far too large.

Can you try again? I added this: force_style='fontsize=22

Ricardo Bohner: I replaced the old script you wrote with the one you just edited to include a forced font style of some sort and the outcome was basically the same: files.catbox.moe/jlubw3.png

Can you share part of the original video where there are some dialoges for example from 5 to 6 minutes ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00 -to 00:06:00 -i "input.mkv" -c copy "output.mkv" and upload the video somewhere?

Ricardo Bohner: Yes, I can. Should I add those arguments to the same script or just input them as-is?

Here is a link to a minute of the file that should contain subtitling: https://files.catbox.moe/d3rzre.mkv

I think I got it now, the error is when you try to force ass subtitles to srt and somehow the font gets set to size 71 while normal subtitle size is about 22...I implemented a way to tell if the subtitle is ass or srt and export \ import it accordingly to the video, please ty.

Ricardo Bohner: Thank you for all your help. The script works great and I understand ffmpeg a little more. Unfortunately, I am having trouble getting the files to play on a Xbox 360 from a USB drive (though that issue is outside the scope of the original query so I will leave it at that). I regrettably can't give you a positive vote as my account lacks the reputation score necessary to do so, but I very much appreciate all the help you have provided for me.

The xbox documentation says something about it supports h.264 AVCHD codec...
